# loading mmdb file using getClassLoader().getResource() returns null although the file exist in the resources

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, geolocation, resources, classloader

i have this piece of code :

```
class GeoLocator{
    public GeoLocator() throws IOException {
            final URL url = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("GeoLite2-Country.mmdb");
            if (url == null) {
                throw new IOException("File not found!");
            }
    }
}
```

and in my main class :

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            GeoLocator geoLocator = new GeoLocator();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

my goal is to load an mmdb file located in the resources in my project.
when I run the main function, I catch an exception :

```
java.io.IOException: File not found!
    at com.a.GeoLocator.<init>(GeoLocator.java:19)
    at com.a.Main.main(Main.java:11)
```

the file hierarchy in my project is as follow:

```
-main
    -java
        -com.a
            GeoLocator.java
            Main.java

    -resources
        GeoLite2-Country.mmdb
```

I have tried to run the code with the absolute and relative path but did not work.

i am using IntelliJ

Is there any thing to do with it?

Comment: You probably need to rename `resourses` to `resources`, which is where Maven expects to find resources by default.

Comment: acctually it is named `resources` just wrote it wrong in the post. i will fix that typo here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the thing that was missing is:

```
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/GeoLite2-Country.mmdb</include>
                    <include>**/apache.log</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
```

in the pom.xml file